# How to pronounce this phrase

Tags: pronunciation

Phrase: `I thought I heard a sound there.`

How do you transition from the word `sound` to `there`? I find it hard to go from the `d` sound to the `th` sound. When speaking fast, do you just ignore the `d` from `sound`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I think I drop the /d/ entirely.

English permits a lot of complex consonant clusters, and speakers simplify at least some of them except when speaking very carefully, for example in public speaking.  It probably varies from speaker to speaker (and to some extent for the same speaker), so I can't give you a precise set of rules for when to make these simplifications.

But in this case I think you're right: in *sound there* the consonant cluster /ndð/ can be simplified to /nð/.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking as a **southern-England native English speaker**: Yes, I merge the words "sound there", since `d` to `th` is difficult to do. I omit the `d` sound and link straight to `th`, resulting in:
`sounthere`

Of course, I can't speak for all of the English-speaking world, but that's how we (in my part of the country) do it.

Remember also your [Schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) (ə) sound on the article "a". Since it's not an important word (at least in this example), we don't pronounce it fully, resulting in an "uh".